Blender 4.2 boolean not working
I've been trying for two days to get this fixed. But Blender does very weird stuff when I do boolean operations with the bool tool.
The result image you see shows a box with objects in but not correct. It's a mould where the shape inside should be cut out of the box to create a three part mould.
When you look in the blend file it shows that the box has a face or the upper circle has a face, but it's impossible to remove the face. Everything is just not working as it should.
I have Blender 4.2 with the latest loop/bool tool etc...
I have no clue what's going on or what I should do.


Here is the file

hello, your link doesn't work, please provide a valid link

added new link @moonboots

Your blend file doesn't actually have a boolean modifier in it so it's difficult to tell exactually what you ar trying to do. However, the bottom bowl (Vorm box.001) and Plane1 have inverted normals on them whch you can see by turning on Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlays menu which will cause any bool modifier problems. In Edit mode select All and hit Shift-N to correct them on each object. Then try again.

Oops! That was posted before I unhid the Test 1 Collection in the Outliner however my comment about correcting the face normals still applies.

Hi the comment about the normals helped definitely for some/most parts.
I got new issues with lines that inflict bevel, but that's something else I have to figure out or ask later.
